# How to set the default error message in mvc2 validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I change the default error message for required rule validation for example?

Comment: Struts?

It would be good to be more specific so others can answer your question without guessing

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Localizing ASP.NET Validation blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/12/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx) of Phil Haack.

Comment: I don't want to write for each field this :
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Mandatory field not provided")]

I want to change the default message that mvc2 gives me

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own MyRequiredAttribute in wich change the default error message and use it.